# Sigma-field under a certain probability measure

Tags: measure-theory

I would like to know how to find the σ-field generated by a random variable *Y* defined as *Y(a)=Y(c)=1*, *Y(b)=Y(d)=-1* , under the sample space *Ω = {a,b,c,d}* and the probability measure *P* defined as *P({a})=P({b})=1/4, P({c})=1/6* and *P({d})=1/3*.

I believe that the σ-field generated by a *r.v. Y*, to keep the same notation, is equal to *Y<sup>-1</sup>[B(ℜ)]* where *B(ℜ)* denotes the Borel σ-field.

What I'm thinking here is that the σ-field generated by *Y* will be {∅,Ω,{b,d},{a,c}}.

Comment: Again, complete incoherence between the level of the question and the requisites necessary to even make sense of the user previous questions (about "Brownian Motions, Filtrations and Expected Values", "Stochastic DEs" and "Brownian Motions and Martingales", to name a few recent examples).

Comment: I post my questions, people understand and are able to help me, why do you have to pick on me every time I post?

Comment: We know you understand perfectly well the problem, but here we go again: some questions asked by your account are completely elementary while others presuppose a rather advanced knowledge to be even formulated. Since they usually contain no context, they (should be closed and) are difficult to answer properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sigma(Y) &= \sigma(\{Y^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal B_{\mathbb R}\})\\ 
&= \sigma(\{Y^{-1}(\{1\}),Y^{-1}(\{-1\})\}\\
&= \sigma(\{\{a,c\},\{b,d\})\\
&= \{\varnothing, \{a,c\}, \{b,d\}, \Omega\}.
\end{align}

Comment: Great, now how do I get E(X|Y)? Just add E(X|Y=-1) and E(X|Y=1)? @math1000

Comment: the 1 denotes the indicator function right?

Comment: and also, is E(X 1.) = E(X)*E(1.) ? @Math1000

Comment: No. For an event $A$, $\mathsf 1_A$ is the random variable defined by $$\mathsf 1_A(\omega) = \begin{cases}1,&\omega\in A\\0,&\omega\notin A.\end{cases} $$

Comment: @Math1000 The formula in your first comment is wrong. Note that the RHS you suggest is simply a real number.

Comment: $$
\mathbb E[X\mid Y](\omega) = \begin{cases}
\mathbb E[X\mid Y=1],& \omega\in\{a,c\}\\
\mathbb E[X\mid Y=-1],& \omega\in\{b,d\}\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Indeed, which is not the formula you wrote in a previous (upvoted...) comment.

Comment: @Did I stand corrected, thanks.